# Why should you avoid the then keyword in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

It's mentioned in several Ruby style guides that you should "Never use then."  Personally, I think the "then" keyword allows you to make code denser, which tends to be harder to read.  Is there any other justification for this recommendation?

Answer (score 19):

I almost never use the `then` keyword. However, there is one case where I believe it greatly improves readability.  Consider the following multi conditional if statements.

**Example A**

```
if customer.jobs.present? && customer.jobs.last.date.present? && (Date.today - customer.jobs.last.date) <= 90
  puts 'Customer had a job recently'
end
```

Line length too long. Hard to read.

**Example B**

```
if customer.jobs.present? &&
   customer.jobs.last.date.present? &&
   (Date.today - customer.jobs.last.date) <= 90
  puts 'Customer had a job recently'
end
```

Where do the conditions end and where does the inner code begin.  According to must Ruby Style Guides, you to have one extra space of indentation for multi line conditionals, but I still don't find it all the easy to read.

**Example C**

```
if customer.jobs.present? &&
   customer.jobs.last.date.present? &&
   (Date.today - customer.jobs.last.date) <= 90
then
  puts 'Customer had a job recently'
end
```

To me, Example C is by far the most clear.  And it is the use of the `then` that does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

If I remember correctly, `then` is just one of the delimiters to separate the condition from the true part (semicolon and newline being the others)

if you have an if statement that is a one-liner, you'd have to use one of the delimiters.

`if (1==2) then puts "Math doesn't work" else puts "Math works!" end`

for multi-line ifs, `then` **is optional** (newline works)

```
if (1==2) 
    puts "Math doesn't work" 
else 
    puts "Math works!" 
end
```

Could you post a link to one of the style-guides that you mention...

Comment: Of course, we can often (always?) replace one-liners with ternary operator uses, e.g. `puts 'Math ' + (1==2 ? "doesn't work" : 'works!')` Not necessarily saying we *should*, mind you, just that it's an option

Comment: A ternary operator is a replacement for an if/then/else statement. It isn't a replacement for if/then.

Comment: @Mike - interesting point. My only issue with ternary operators is that it can hurt readability sometimes (and they're a bit obtuse for beginners). For small one-liners, I agree it could be a feasible alternative or the if-modifier approach of `greet_user if someone_is_logged_in`

Answer (score 4):

I think "never use `then`" is wrong. Using too much non-alphabet characters can make code as difficult to read as perl or APL. Using a natural language word often makes the programmer more comfortable. It depends on the balance between readability and compactness of the code. Ternary operator is occasionally convinient, but is ugly if misused.