# Find a string in a file and return the value before the string using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am in the process of learning ruby. I am trying to read a file, find a string, and return the value before the string.

I've tried this:

```
line = "ALTER TABLE schemaname.tablename MODIFY col1 number(19,0)"
bol1 = line.include?("MODIFY")
puts "{#bol1}" 

if bol1 = "true"
  if line =~ /ALTER TABLE/ then
    drop_found = "true"
    location = line.index("ALTER TABLE") + 11
    subline = line[location..-1]
    sublineParts = subline.split(" ")
    tableName = sublineParts[0]
    puts " found modify column on {#tableName}"
   end
   else
     puts " no modify found"
   end
```

I don't get any output here. `bol1 = line.include?("MODIFY")` returns nothing. Please help.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528281/ruby-parsing-a-text-file

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, specifying where you're stuck, what code you've tried. Please review [mcve]

Comment: You have a lot of unused variables in the second if block.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @0012 , That's not intentional. I just tried it this way

Comment: @shriBin you should leave an example of the problem you are trying to solve.   Any reason why you removed it?

Comment: Rolled back. Removing that much content from your question makes it off-topic and invalidates the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few errors/style concerns:

- You're using an assignment equals in your conditional.  `bol1 = "true"` should be `bol1 == "true"` But:
- You're checking to see if the `.include?` function returned the string `"true"` You should check if the value *is* true. (`bol1 == true` or just `if (bol1)`) This is why you're not getting back the value you expect.
- [`then` is rarely used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659360/why-should-you-avoid-the-then-keyword-in-ruby) but not never.
- If you're going to use `then` it closes the if statement, the if statement doesn't need an end unless it's completely by itself.  `else` will also close the `if` block.
- You're missing a closing `end` at the bottom
- You've tried to puts `"{#bol1}"` instead of `"#{bol1}"` which is [how variable interpolation works](http://batsov.com/articles/2014/08/13/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-14-variable-interpolation/).  (You can just `puts bol1` though, it would be easier. No need to use `#{}`)

The working version of your program I've got is this:

```
line = "ALTER TABLE schemaname.tablename MODIFY col1 number(19,0)"
bol1 = line.include?("MODIFY")
puts bol1

if (bol1)
  if (line =~ /ALTER TABLE/)
    drop_found = true
    location = line.index("ALTER TABLE") + 11
    subline = line[location..-1]
    sublineParts = subline.split(" ")
    tableName = sublineParts[0]
    puts " found modify column on {#tableName}"
  else
    puts " no modify found"
  end
end
```

Comment: This works.. Thanks for your help and explanation @0112

Comment: You're welcome.  Best of luck learning ruby.

Comment: @shriBin since you have two nested if blocks, you should also probably just use an and statement like `if (bol1 && line =~ /ALTER TABLE/)`.  I don't know if you have a specific reason for doing it the way you're doing though.  Just a suggestion.